# Java regex pattern with optional string

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like these:

```
something something [[abcd]] blah blah
something something [[xyz|abcd]] blah blah
```

What I want in both cases is:

```
something something abcd blah blah
```

How do I do this using only 1 regex pattern in Java? I can do the first case with this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.+?)\\]\\]");
Matcher m = patternLinkRemoval.matcher(text);
return m.replaceAll("$1");
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse MediaWiki-Syntax - maybe a parser from http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers would be a better alternative as MediaWiki has quite a few strange edge cases.

Comment: Looks like a helpful source. Thanks!

Comment: Sweble looks rather nice: http://sweble.org/crystalball/?wicket:interface=:11:query-form::IFormSubmitListener::&stage=POSTPRO&expMode=NOT_APPLICABLE&format=TEXT&query:wikitext=something+something+%5B%5Babcd%5D%5D+blah+blah%0Asomething+something+%5B%5Bxyz%7Cabcd%5D%5D+blah+blah

Comment: If you use Eclipse, check out this plugin: http://myregexp.com/eclipsePlugin.html I find it pretty useful, especially when "designing" the regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following:

- Anything except `|` zero or more times: `[^|]*`
- ...followed by a `|`: `|`
- ...optionally: `?`
- Group it using `(?: ... )` if you don't want to capture the thing.

Here's a complete example:

```
String text1 = "something something [[abcd]] blah blah";
String text2 = "something something [[xyz|abcd]] blah blah";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(?:[^|]*\\|)?(.+?)\\]\\]");

System.out.println(pattern.matcher(text1).replaceAll("$1"));
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(text2).replaceAll("$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
something something abcd blah blah
something something abcd blah blah
```

Comment: Thanks, accepting your answer instead of mine for the quick respond!

Comment: ...and change the replaceAll to use $2, I guess.

Comment: @Disco3, the `(?: ... )` doesn't capture anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself! `\\[\\[(?:.+?\\|)?(.+?)\\]\\]`