# JavaScript RegEx pattern with optional substring

Tags: javascript, regex, web-scraping

I want to write a regular expression in JavaScript that works unconditionally WRT the presence (or absence) of an optional substring within a repeated pattern. (In other words, I want it to work whether or not the substring is present.)

In the example below, consider the repeated pattern to begin with the string `beg` and end with the string `end`. The data I seek to extract are the strings `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `bat` and `qux`. As you can see, the complication is the presence of the optional substring `bat` and what surrounds it.

Below is the example to solve.

### Example

[To see the live demo, click here](https://regex101.com/r/jZ7sU3/1).

https://regex101.com/r/jZ7sU3/1

Consider the following regular expression:

```
/beg(.*?)end/g
```

acting on the following content:

```
beg foo end beg bar end beg baz (bat) end beg qux end
```

produces the following result:

> Match 1: `foo`
>
> Match 2: `bar`
>
> Match 3: `baz (bat)`
>
> Match 4: `qux`

but the result I seek is as follows:

> Match 1: `foo`
>
> Match 2: `bar`
>
> Match 3: `baz`
>
> Match 4: `bat`
>
> Match 5: `qux`

Can anyone figure out the solution?

[Here is a similar question for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11101649/1640892).

Comment: I don't understand. You say "I seek 3 matches as follows", but then list four matches. The regexp you give refers to neither "end" nor "data". Please give an entire input string with the precise desired output.

Comment: @torazaburo: I just corrected it to read "four matches." Is that sufficient? Or do you need more clarification?

Comment: I don't understand how the presence or absence of the parentheses or the "optional" string would affect trying to retrieve things of the form `data\d`, if that's what you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: try https://regex101.com/r/jP0bP8/1

Comment: @torazaburo: Point taken. That was my fault for making a bad example. Or one that was too easily solved without addressing the crux of the matter. I have edited the question to show a better example, I think. Please let me know if it's okay and clear now.

Comment: @Saleem: Thank but not it. That was the point torazaburo made. I had to correct the example to prevent that solution as that is not what I was after. The issue is the optional substring `bat`.

Comment: @Mowzer checkout updated post below. https://regex101.com/r/jP0bP8/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex, it should match

```
/(?:beg (.*?)(?=\(|end))|\((.*?)\)/g
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP0bP8/2) at regex101.